# openURL to find my iPhone

Tags: iphone, openurl

I was wondering if it's possible to open the "find my iPhone" app from my own app with openURL, but can't figure the url scheme it has. Anyone can help me with this or is it a useless task? I've managed to open some third party apps and also some of the Apple apps (for instance open a book on the iBookStore) but I've been trying to open this "Find my iPhone" with no successs. Any hints?

Comment: If your iPhone is jailbroken, you can navigate using iFile to `~/Applications/GUID-OF-FIND-MY-IPHONE/FindMyiPhone.app/Info.plist` and read the URL Scheme there.

If your iPhone is not jailbroken, I can personally go into mine and see if I can find the URL scheme

Comment: I don't have my iPhone jailbroken, I would appreciate if you could seek into it

Comment: It appears that 'Find My iPhone' doesn't respond to any document types or URL schemes, which means you cannot launch it from your application.

Comment: OK thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are complete websites collecting iPhone URL schemes, for example [this one](http://applookup.com/). But for "Find my iPhone" there is nothing, so I am afraid the answer will be "you can't".