# Find My iPhone app url scheme

Tags: ios, url-scheme, openurl

Does the 'Find My iPhone' app have a published URL scheme that can be used to launch the app from another app?

I found the same question being posed a few years back: [openURL to find my iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584945/openurl-to-find-my-iphone). Was wondering if there might be a url scheme available now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Subash still apple did not provide url scheme for Find My iPhone app.

[Apple url scheme documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference.pdf#page4) does not mention about Find My iPhone

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Apple does now have a published URL scheme to Launch the Find My app on Mac and iPhone.

Open Find My app:

```
findmy://
```

Open Find My app to the People tab:

```
findmy://friends
```

Open Find My app to the Devices tab:

```
findmy://devices
```

Open Find My app to the Items tab:

```
findmy://items
```